# Java Executing ssh command through java code

Tags: java, linux, ssh

I am looking for a simple way to execute the ssh command in my java program. Basically I gather user input and based on their choices on hosts I want to execute the ssh command and let the linux shell command take over.
I have the feeling that a scripting language would be better suited but this is urgent and I have no experience in scripting.
I have tried something like the following based on info I gathered on the site:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh myusername@ipaddress");
```

However it doesn't seem to work
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error? What do you see? The only thing I can tell is that there is no problem in calling ssh from Java using Runtime.getRuntime()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)?  It seems to be what you need.

Scripting is super easy as well.  Just take all the commands you would execute on a terminal and put them in the script.  send in the arguments(usersnames/password,hosts,etc..) and you're good to go.

Either way, good luck.

Comment: So I have implemented jsch into my code. However the interaction with the host server is done in the java program.
What I want is to: one read an xml file that contains multiple hosts( name, ipaddress, password) prompt user for choices. Once I gather all this info all I want is execute the ssh command with the values and exit the program.
This doesn't seem to be the case with jcraft

Answer (score 0):

For a free component, look at [Ganymed SSH](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/).